# Javafx: cannot load fxml despite right name and path

Tags: java, javafx

I'm new to javafx and I don't understand why my getResource doesn't work to open fxml files. I'm pretty positive my name and paths are correct but the console shows

I have changed the error message to the new one

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at application.Main.start(Main.java:31)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
```

Exception running application application.Main

This apparently shows that the name for the loader is incorrect or the path is wrong, which I don't believe to be the case for me. Here is a picture of my build path

[image]

Here's my main code

```
package application;

import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Main.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("Main.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

could this be an error with my fxml coding (made it with scene builder)

Sorry if this is a very simple question.

FXML code (I deleted a few textboxes to make room for 30k characters)

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.java">
   <top>
      <VBox prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label text="Attacker">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <GridPane prefHeight="60.0">
              <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
              </columnConstraints>
              <rowConstraints>
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
              </rowConstraints>
               <children>
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Units" />
                  <Label text="Amount" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="Losses" textFill="#fc0303" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Spear" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Sword" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Axe" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Archer" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="LC" GridPane.columnIndex="5" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="MA" GridPane.columnIndex="6" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="HC" GridPane.columnIndex="7" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Ram" GridPane.columnIndex="8" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Catapult" GridPane.columnIndex="9" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Berserk" GridPane.columnIndex="10" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="10" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="10" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Treb" GridPane.columnIndex="11" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="11" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="11" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Noble" GridPane.columnIndex="12" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Paladin" GridPane.columnIndex="13" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="13" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="13" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Remaining" textFill="#02f858" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="10" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="11" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="13" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
               </children>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </GridPane>
            <Label text="Defender">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
            </Label>
            <GridPane prefHeight="60.0">
               <children>
                  <Label prefHeight="17.0" prefWidth="50.0" text="Units" />
                  <Label text="Amount" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="Losses" textFill="#fc0303" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Spear" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Sword" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Axe" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Archer" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="LC" GridPane.columnIndex="5" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="MA" GridPane.columnIndex="6" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="HC" GridPane.columnIndex="7" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Ram" GridPane.columnIndex="8" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Catapult" GridPane.columnIndex="9" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Berserk" GridPane.columnIndex="10" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="10" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="10" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Treb" GridPane.columnIndex="11" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="11" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="11" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Noble" GridPane.columnIndex="12" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Paladin" GridPane.columnIndex="13" />
                  <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="13" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="RED" GridPane.columnIndex="13" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                  <Label text="Remaining" textFill="#02f858" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="7" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="8" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="9" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="10" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="11" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="12" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                  <Label text="0" textFill="LIME" GridPane.columnIndex="13" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
               </children>
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="120.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                  <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                  <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
               </rowConstraints>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets left="10.0" right="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </GridPane>
         </children>
      </VBox>
   </top>
   <bottom>
      <GridPane>
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="24.0328369140625" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="21.04925537109375" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="38.95074462890625" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="24.08203125" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints maxHeight="38.95074462890625" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="44.91796875" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Attacking losses" textAlignment="CENTER" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Defending losses" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Wood" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Clay" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Iron" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Provision" GridPane.columnIndex="4" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="Time spent" GridPane.columnIndex="5" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Bashpoints gained" GridPane.columnIndex="6" />
            <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="6" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
   </bottom>
   <center>
      <GridPane gridLinesVisible="true" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <columnConstraints>
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
            <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
            <RowConstraints maxHeight="42.0" minHeight="0.0" prefHeight="0.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
            <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Label text="Attacker" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Spearman" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Swordsman" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <Label text="Axe Fighter" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <Label text="Archer" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <Label text="Light Cavalry" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <Label text="Mounted Archer" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <Label text="Heavy Cavalry" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <Label text="Ram" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <Label text="Catapult" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
            <Label text="Berserker" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
            <Label text="Nobleman" GridPane.rowIndex="13" />
            <Label text="Trebuchet" GridPane.rowIndex="12" />
            <Label text="Defender" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Paladin" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="13" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="12" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="9" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="8" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="7" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="6" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="5" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="4" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="14" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="13" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="12" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="10" />
            <TextField alignment="CENTER" text="0" GridPane.columnIndex="2" GridPane.rowIndex="11" />
            <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="4" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <ComboBox prefWidth="150.0" GridPane.columnIndex="5" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Church Level" GridPane.columnIndex="3" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <Label text="Morale (%)" GridPane.columnIndex="3" 
         </padding>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </GridPane>
   </center>
</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Please post your `Main.fxml` code. There is something wrong with it at line 9. There is nothing wrong with your path to the FXML.

Comment: I have posted the fxml code. Is it because of the infinite height and width?

Comment: you must specify the fully qualified name of the controller class - from your screenshot it seems to reside in package `application`, so the param must be `application.Controller` (without file extension, the loader is looking for a class)

Comment: I have changed it to application.Controller, but it still shows exceptions pointing to the getResource()

Comment: Why do you think it can't find the FXML file? Since it's explicitly telling you which line of the FXML file the problem is on, it surely must be able to find the file. Include the *complete* stack trace in the question.

Comment: updated the question with new error

Answer (score 0):

## There are a few problems with your project.

### Resource locations

You should put resources like FXML- and CSS-files in the `resources/` directory. That's what it's for. Now you can access your resources via `this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("resourcename.ext")`. Notice `getClassLoader()`: Calling it is more comfortable since you can omit the `/` at the beginning of every resource.

#### Quick example (Class vs. ClassLoader):

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("someresource.txt");
```

is equivalent to

```
this.getClass().getResource("/someresource.txt");
```

---

Your project structure should now look like this:

[image: Project structure]

Note: Don't bother about the `main/` and `java/` directories, that's just the maven standard I use. Important is that you've got `Controller.java` and `Main.java` in the `application`-package and `Main.css` and `Main.fxml` directly under `resources/`.

Note: If you have more files than just the Main view's FXML and CSS you might want to add a directory for each view.

---

Your `Application#start(Stage)`-method should now look like this:

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Main.fxml"));

    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    scene.getStylesheets().add(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Main.css").toExternalForm());
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

### Line 9 in your FXML

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="Controller.java">
```

should be

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefWidth="1000.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.Controller">
```

`Controller.java` -> `application.Controller`
As the `fx:controller` attribute takes a "fully qualified classname" (packagename + classname) and not a filepath as an argument.

Comment: I changed line 9. I also tried putting it under resources but it still shows an error message... this is really weird, I have tried javafx scene builder before successfully.

Comment: I disagree quite fundamentally with your first point. I think the `resources` structure in the source structure is designed more for server-side code, where it makes a lot of sense to deploy those resources to a different location than the class files. Since there is such a strong coupling between an FXML file and its controller class, I usually find it (much) better in a large project to keep the two together, both in source and build hierarchies. Then (because they are in the same package) you can do `Controller.class.getResource("Main.fxml")`, which is really natural.

Comment: @James_D Well for me putting it in the package and doing just `class.getResource("Main.fxml")` returns null.

Comment: Are you using Maven? (This looks like a standard Maven layout.) Sometimes you have to configure it to to deploy resources defined from the `src` hierarchy. (The same may be true in IntelliJ, which I don't use.)

Comment: The problem is, that once the project grows to a size where it's infeasible to have a single resources folder for all your FXML files, you end up manually replicating the hierarchy under `resources` that you have under `src` for the controllers. It's a lot more manageable if you don't have to replicate the same hierarchy in two different places.

Comment: @James_D You're right, that would be very inconvenient. I just never made *such* a big project before where it would have become a problem.